# convert 4 bytes to float matlab

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I read from the serial port 4 bytes and I want to create a Matlab
 function to convert them into a float number 
  for example: if I read     A=[65 240 0 0] I must have 30 according to
   IEEE754 standard.
 - I have used Simulink block "byte unpack" but i have problems. in fact
   I    should read over 18 parameters. each parameters is 4 bytes
   array.then I should use 18 byte unpack.

Comment: you want to create a function, or use a built-in one : [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html)

Comment: As suggested in one of the answers, you may not be using the byte unpack block correctly. It may just be a matter of changing the endian setting in the block. You don't say how you use and parameterise the block, nor what "problems" you have with it.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Matlab will use double precision to store any new value which doesn't have a type specified. If you know you are reading `byte`, then the best is to collect them directly as `uint8` (the unsigned byte type of Matlab) if you can (in your call to `fread` or equivalent).

If you cannot collect them directly as `uint8` then cast them as such then use the [`typecast`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function.

```
A = [65 240 0 0] ; %// Collected bytes

A = uint8(A) ;                      %// cast them to "uint8" if they are not already
Afloat = typecast( A , 'single') ;  %// cast the 4 bytes as a 32 bit float
```

wait a minute:

```
Afloat =
   8.6186862e-41
```

oops, it seems the byte ordering used by your collection mechanism is the opposite as the one used by Matlab. No problem, you can just change the endianness by "flipping" the byte array.

So instead, use:

```
>> Afloat = typecast( fliplr(A) , 'single')
Afloat =
    30
```

success :)

You can also look at the function [`swapbytes`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) to manage the endianess.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid reinventing the wheel, simply use

```
A = fread(obj,size,'precision')
```

as described in [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html)

For example,

```
[A,count] = fread(obj, 18, 'float32');
```

should read 18 4 byte floats.

Comment: Depending on how he is receiving the data and from which device it is not always possible (some device send byte 1 by one and you have to acknoledge before receiving the next one). But if he can indeed read the 4 bytes directly with `fread`, you should mention the last parameter `machineformat` which will specify the byte ordering. He seems to need it ;-)